# How to decipher coding on Voltage Regulator

Tags: voltage-regulator, identification

[image]

I am looking to replace the voltage regulator above but I am not able to find an exact replacement and am not sure what the last three digits "203" stand for. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: can you add more information.  For example the complete part number if there is any, the output voltage and current?  any information about the circuit that might be useful in helping select a replacement part

Comment: Pls add a photo.

Comment: That can be LM7805 as well, Usually 5V regulator. Make sure of the current rating you are looking, as per your circuit. https://www.fairchildsemi.com/datasheets/LM/LM7805.pdf

Answer (score 6):

7805A is the part number - standard +5V regulator.

Usually the other numbers are things like batch numbers, lot codes, production dates etc. You are highly unlikely to find one where these numbers are identical to yours, but then you don't need to. *Theoretically* all 7805's should be compatible.

---

As to your one, if you google the part number (7805A) and manufacturer (KIA) you can very easily find the [datasheet](http://www.kec.co.kr/data/databook/pdf/KIA/Eng/KIA7805AP~KIA7824AP.pdf). Generally the package labelling is explained in the datasheet, although not in this one it seems. But at least if you have the datasheet you can find another 7805 and verify that the new one matches the specifications within the range which you are using it.